# Updating text elements in d3.js

Tags: d3.js

Is it possible with d3.js to remove text elements one by one and update them straight away when the element is removed? So for example: there is an initial string with 0's shown in the image, then remove the first text element and then update it straight away and so on.

https://lh4.googleusercontent.com/-BxbMS_JqyO0/UzgsTEC_SgI/AAAAAAAAAAw/tVs3ADJCGJg/s3200/Screen+Shot+2014-03-30+at+15.37.35.png

I have been stuck on this for a while, I can remove all the elements at once but not one by one. Can someone please point me in the right direction? Is there a tutorial which I can look at?

Below is example code:

```
     var stepData = [ [[0,0,0,0,0,0,0],[0,1,1,1,1,1,1],[0,1,2,2,2,2,2],[0,1,2,2,2,2,2]], [[0,0,0,0,0,0,0],[0,0,0,0,0,1,1],[0,1,1,1,1,1,1],[0,1,1,2,2,2,2]] ];
     svgWidth = 600;
     svgHeight = 1000;
     delay = 1000;
     svg = d3.select("body")
             .append("svg")
             .attr("width", svgWidth)
             .attr("height", svgHeight);

svg.append("g")
   .attr("class", "data")
   .selectAll("g")                  
   .data(stepData[0])
   .enter()
   .append("g")
   .selectAll("text")
   .data( function(d,i,j){ 
       return d; 
    })
   .enter()
   .append("text")
   .text( function(d,i,j) { 
     if ( j === 0) {
         return d; 
     }
   })
   .attr("x", function(d,i,j) { return (i * 50) + 50; })
   .attr("y", function(d,i,j) { return (j * 50) + 50; })
   .attr("text-anchor", "middle")
   .attr("fill", "black"); 

svg.select(".data")
   .transition()
   .delay(function(d, i, j) {       
           return i * delay + 1000; 
    })
   .remove();
```

Thank you.

Comment: Yes, you can certainly do this. Can you show us the code you have so far?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you're selecting the `g` element containing *everything* and removing that. Your selection contains only a single element and therefore everything is removed at once. If you instead select the `text` elements, it works fine.

Complete demo [here](http://jsfiddle.net/mM7mL/).

Comment: Thank you! :) that's exactly what I was trying to do.